# How can I make a generated link to a post's original markdown file on GitHub Pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, pull-request

I'm using GitHub Pages to generate [my blog](https://BenLeggiero.blog). I would like to place a link on each post to allow viewers to view the MD source andor create a pull request to suggest a modification of that post.

However, [I can't find](https://www.google.com/search?q=jekyll+link+to+original+git+file) anything describing how to generate such URLs.

I'm thinking something like this:

```jekyll
<a href="{{ post.original.url }}">View Original</a>
```

**Is this possible? And if so, how can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a link directly to each page adding a URL like this to your layout, for example for user john and foo-repo: *https://github.com/john/foo-repo/edit/master/{{ page.path }}*

```
<a href="https://github.com/john/foo-repo/edit/master/{{ page.path }}" class="text-success">

         <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> &nbsp;Improve this page

        </a>
```

I've used this approach, here is an example: https://github.com/marcanuy/jekyll-skeleton/blob/master/_layouts/default.html and working: https://marcanuy.github.io/jekyll-skeleton/